# ActionScript 3 Specification as PDF?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I see the [ActionScript language specification](http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/as3_specification.html), however, the online format is awkward.  Has anyone converted this to a PDF?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a PDF version: https://static.bloople.net/ActionScript%203%20Language%20Specification.pdf

And a single-page HTML version: https://static.bloople.net/as3ls/

These versions are based on the content at http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/as3_specification.html as of today, Wednesday 21 November 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/

and download "Complete Flex 3 Documentation" zip file. It's in from what I remember
(html version though, not PDF)

edit : not up to date docs (langref 3.2 instead of 3.4)

Comment: It's not language specification. It's documentation on standard library and framework.

Answer (score 1):

@bloopletech's host works only periodically.

`web.archive.org` (2017) links:

- [HTML page](http://web.archive.org/web/20170606040559/http://bloople.net/as3ls)
- [PDF](http://web.archive.org/web/20170606040559/http://bloople.net/ActionScript%203%20Language%20Specification.pdf)